# Python script cannot find module folder in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a simple Python script.

**main.py**

```
try:
    from Core.banner import banner
except:
    print("Core folder not found")
    exit()
```

**Core/banner.py**

```
def banner():
    print("I am a banner")
```

**folder structure**

```
Core/
  __init__.py
  banner.py
main.py
```

When I run `!python main.py`, it said:

> Core folder not found

but I confirmed the `Core/banner.py` exists by `%ls -al`.

However, the same script can run in a local machine without problem.

The full Jupyter notebook contents and output are:

```
!git clone https://github.com/xxx/myproject.git
cloning into 'myproject'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 82, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 82 (delta 1), reused 10 (delta 1), pack-reused 72
Unpacking objects: 100% (82/82), done.
total 267592
%cd myproject
%ls -al
/home/jovyan/myproject
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 4 jovyan users  4096 Jan 31 01:55 ./
drwxrwxrwx 7 root   root   4096 Jan 31 01:55 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 jovyan users  4096 Jan 31 01:55 Core/
drwxr-xr-x 8 jovyan users  4096 Jan 31 01:55 .git/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jovyan users 15082 Jan 31 01:55 main.py*
!python main.py
Core folder not found
```

What did I miss?

Note: already tried to restart the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a `__init__.py` file in the `Core` folder and then use the following code.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./Core/')
```

It should look like this:

```
try:
    import sys
    sys.path.append('./Core/')
    from Core.banner import banner
except:
    print("Core folder not found")
    exit()
```

Comment: I added the contents in `__init__.py` and works. The 2 lines in the `main.py` is not required. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you add those two lines in ```__init__.py```, it should work also. The system just needs to know where the module is

Comment: but why does the script runs normally in local system?

Comment: By local machine, you mean from the folder if you run ```python main.py```?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to treat `Core` as a module but you need to add an `__init__.py` file under Core in order to accomplish that:

```
Core/
  __init__.py
  banner.py
main.py
```

Comment: Actually, I have the file, but it's empty; I thought it's useless, so I omit it from the question. Let me update the question.

Comment: It's kinda useless.... but it does tell Python that the folder is a module. It can have some other initialization stuff but as long as it's included then the only thing you're probably missing is what ksohan mentioned: to have Python include the folder (local or absolute path) to the system path.