# I can't set global variables and functions when creating a __init__.py file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on this small project, and I want to learn how to use packaging and folder structures well. I have thus created a `__init__.py` file, which is supposed to make sure that there are 2 objects readily available whenever I am writing on a file:

- a dataframe
- the functions i created in another file called tracks_functions.py

Making the dataframe readily available wasn't an issue, but I can't seem to make the functions available. This is the current setup code for the `__init__.py` file:

```
import pandas as pd

import os

# To use only if you want to change the path of the dataset
# import sys
# sys.path.append("folder/data")
# os.chdir("folder/data")

print(f"Importing the Top 50 Spotify Tracks dataset as a pandas dataframe.")

df = pd.read_csv(
    "folder/data/spotifytoptracks.csv",
    index_col=0,
)

print(os.listdir())
make_corr = tracks_functions.make_corr
print_corr_matrix = tracks_functions.print_corr_matrix
```

And here is what the output looks like:

```
(.venv) [folder]$ folder/.venv/bin/python folder/py_scripts/__init__.py
Importing the Top 50 Spotify Tracks dataset as a pandas dataframe.
['.git', '125.ipynb', '.venv', '.gitignore', '__pycache__', '.vscode', 'data', 'data_exploration_cleaning', 'py_scripts', 'tracks_analysis_correlations.ipynb', 'tracks_analysis.ipynb']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folder/py_scripts/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    make_corr = tracks_functions.make_corr
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'tracks_functions' is not defined
```

You can see that the `print(os.listdir())` call does show 'py_scripts' in the list. So why am I not able to obtain these functions in the `__init__.py` if I make sure I import them from tracks_functions?

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? This is the current structure of the folders:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but, no, I can't `"see that the print(..."` code in that image. Please replace the image with the text of your code.

Comment: Ok sorry one second.

Comment: Ok, now I can't see any code at all. I can see the error traceback which is good, but I need the code to make sense of it.

Comment: Sorry for the mess of edits, the code should be visible now.

Comment: I think you need to have `import tracks_functions` near the top of your `__init__.py` file.

Comment: "So why am I not able to obtain these functions in the `__init__.py` if I make sure I import them from tracks_functions?": because you're *not* importing these functions.

Comment: Tip, if you surround a filename with backticks, ` , then the double underscores in `__init__.py` will be visible, instead of turning into a bold __init__.py filename.

Comment: I tried to add `import tracks_functions` at the top, but I still get an error in my main file:

NameError: name 'print_corr_matrix' is not defined

Which is a function in the tracks_functions module

Comment: If you have added `import tracks_functions` and now you get a different error, then we have solved your problem, but really that was just a typo.

Comment: @quamrana yeah, the issue is now with the main file. Which in the picture is 'tracks_analysis_correlations.ipynb'. I write import py_scripts, and try to call the print_corr_matrix function but get told that it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I found out thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70920757/python-script-cannot-find-module-folder-in-jupyter-notebook) how I was supposed to manage the folder. The `__init__.py` file is now empty besides a print line. Then I set two modules which I can import whenever from py_scripts.module import and it all works just fine.